# use feature selection to select best 2048 instead of 4096

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, feature-selection

im still beginner with DL, I'm trying to do image classification using VGG16 pre-trained model and dumb the features into csv file, and I have got 4096 features as the below results :

```
1       2       3       4     ...  4096
0.12    0.23    0.345   0.5372 ... 0.21111
0.2313  0.321   0.214   0.3542 ... 0.46756
.
.
```

I'm trying to use `SelectKBest` feature selection to select the best 2048 features instead of 4096, can you show me how please

i have tried :

```
data = pd.read_csv("multiClassVGG16.csv")
array = data.values
X = array[:,1:]
Y = array[:,0]

test = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=4)
fit = test.fit(X,Y)

# Summarize scores
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(fit.scores_)

features = fit.transform(X)
# # Summarize selected features
print(features[0:2048,:])

# Feature extraction
model = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFE(model, 2048)
fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
print("Num Features: %s" % (fit.n_features_))
print("Selected Features: %s" % (fit.support_))
print("Feature Ranking: %s" % (fit.ranking_))
```

im just looking to regenerate a new dataframe with best 2048 features  to dump it again to csv
desired results :

```
1       2       3       4     ...  2048
0.12    0.23    0.345   0.5372 ... 0.21111
0.2313  0.321   0.214   0.3542 ... 0.46756
```

Comment: After `fit()`, make use of the [`transform()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.transform) method to reduce X to the selected features. You can then save the selected features to a CSV file.

Comment: @skillsmuggler can you show me how in the answer section please ? appreciated your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature extraction part should be something along the lines of

```py
# Feature extraction
model = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFE(model, 2048)
rfe.fit(X, Y)

# Extracting 2048 features
feat = rfe.transform(X)
feat.shape
# (n_rows, 2048)

# Save to CSV
np.savetxt("foo.csv", feat, delimiter=",")
```

You can make use of the `fit_transform()` method to combine the process of fitting the data to the feature extractor as well as extracting the required features.

Go through the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) to better understand the additional functionalities available as part of the method.